# When using Structure, how do I use a different template for category pages?

Tags: templates, categories, structure

I'm using Structure in a new EE site and I'm wondering, what's the best way to use a different template when on a category page? For example, I have a section called "Watch" located here:

`/watch/`

When clicking on a category (film genre) you land here:

`/watch/genre/comedy`

Then when clicking on a film you land here:

`/watch/film/superman`

All three of these pages have different templates. I have the `/watch/` index template worked out, as well as the detail template for `/watch/film/superman`. It's the category template for `/watch/genre/comedy` that I'm unclear about.

Will I need to tackle this with conditional `{if …}{/if}` statements in a single template, or is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you'd need to have a placeholder page to show categories because adding random segments to Structure URLs will result in a 404. Or, you can use conditionals in one main template like you mentioned and use Freebie to allow random segments: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie. Option #2 is more flexible.